# convert stored()[:10] function in python to .net syntax (pythonnet)

Tags: python, .net, .net-core, python.net

I have python script and I try to rewrite it using pythonnet in .net. This  But i confuse how to convert this line in python to .net?

```
contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using System.Linq;

```
var sorted = contours
  .OrderByDescending(c => c.ContourArea)
  .Take(10);
```

Comment: thank you it working well. But i want to mention note for the reader searcher of the same problem that i used cv2 so rather than "c => c.ContourArea" I wrote "cv2.contourArea". of course after importing cv2 "dynamic cv2 = Py.Import("cv2");"